# Xna many mouse buttons

Tags: c#, xna, mouse

How can I get information about additional mouse buttons in xna. For instance, I know I can use MouseState to check if the regular three buttons are pressed but how can I take advantage of something like the G5 or [Naga](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.169418900) mouse which have more than just three buttons?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xna does not support the use of the extra mouse buttons natively. Even the underlying Win32 API only supports up to [two extra buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468874(VS.85).aspx). Any other buttons are supported at the driver level